# Installing libboost-python-dev for python3 without installing python2.7

Tags: 16.04, python3, boost

I am trying to install boost bindings for python3 on Ubuntu Xenial, but it pulls in whole python2.7 dependency tree. I do not want or need python2.7 on my system (Docker image). Is there a way to install only python3 bindings?

Answer (score 11):

I have resolved to compiling and installing boost myself (I also installed/compiled Python 3.6 myself.). I have in my Dockerfile now:

```
# We have to compile it ourselves against the custom Python and cannot use Debian package.
# Includes a symlink workaround for: https://svn.boost.org/trac10/ticket/11120
RUN cd /usr/src && \
 wget --no-verbose https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.65.1/source/boost_1_65_1.tar.gz && \
 tar xzf boost_1_65_1.tar.gz && \
 cd boost_1_65_1 && \
 ln -s /usr/local/include/python3.6m /usr/local/include/python3.6 && \
 ./bootstrap.sh --with-python=$(which python3) && \
 ./b2 install && \
 rm /usr/local/include/python3.6 && \
 ldconfig && \
 cd / && rm -rf /usr/src/*
```

Answer (score 2):

You have three options:

#### 1. Build Boost.Python yourself

This is the option I recommend: it's clean, there's no risk to mess up your system and you have full control on what you get. Moreover<sup>[1](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/python/doc/html/building/installing_boost_python_on_your_.html)</sup>

> Boost.Python is a separately-compiled (as opposed to header-only) library

so you can just build that. Download the archive and follow the instruction on the [Getting Started guide](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html). (This is what [OP did](https://askubuntu.com/a/1094678/873160).)

---

#### 2. Use `dpkg` to avoid installing unwanted dependecies

If you don't want to build Boost.Python yourself, you can bypass `apt` (and its dependencies cheking) with `dpkg`.

Let's say you want to install a package named `foo` which depends on `bar` and `baz`, but you don't actually need `baz`.

```
apt download foo bar
sudo dpkg --ignore-depends=baz --install foo.deb bar.deb
```

Notice that `apt` will still complain about unresolved dependencies (but hey, that's its job), so the problem is not entirely solved: you just swept it under the carpet.

This option is quicker than the previous one, but I wouldn't recommend it.

---

#### 3. Use `equivs` to fool `apt`

This is new to me. Apparently, you can [create dummy packages to fulfill the dependencies](http://shallowsky.com/blog/linux/install/blocking-deb-dependencies.html).
In this way, you don't have to install unwanted/unnecessary packages and `apt` will not complain about it.

As I said, I've never used `equivs` before, but you can find out more about it [here](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/4610).

Comment: instead of conveniently using `foo` and `bar` please solve the problem at hand using libboost and whatnot, because your 2nd solution doesn't help. Too generic to be applicable.

Answer (score 0):

due to my research, it's not possible

`libboost-python-dev` package has `libboost-python1.67-dev` dependency.

https://packages.debian.org/sid/libboost-python-dev

and `libboost-python1.67-dev` has `python-dev` dependency which uses python 2

https://packages.debian.org/sid/libboost-python1.67-dev

so you cannot do this I think you cannot do this in Debian.

I recommend checking `arch base` and `rpm base` distros.

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04 it only uses Python 3 https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libboost-python1.71-dev

Answer (score -3):

I can offer two solutions, one is to build a Python:3.6 image from scratch. Here python3.x becomes the de-facto choice.

Also, another option which worked for me (in Mac OSX) was:

`brew install boost-python --with-python3 --without-python`

Comment: Homebrew on Ubuntu??

Comment: https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-on-Linux